# How can I get sessionId from `PreparedStatement`?

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

How can I get sessionId from `PreparedStatement`?
In debug mode I can this

```
((T4CConnection) ((T4CPreparedStatement) ((OraclePreparedStatementWrapper) ps).preparedStatement).connection).sessionId
```

but how can I get this `sessionId` in my class?

Answer (score 2):

```
Field sessionIdField = ps.getConnection().getClass().getDeclaredField("sessionId");
                    Field serialNumberField = ps.getConnection().getClass().getDeclaredField("serialNumber");
                    sessionIdField.setAccessible(true);
                    serialNumberField.setAccessible(true);
                    Object sessionId = sessionIdField.get(ps.getConnection());
                    Object serialNumber = serialNumberField.get(ps.getConnection());
```